# How to restart Node JS Server in Production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nodemon

I want to have the ability to restart NODE JS server from cli in Production Mode , a script in `Package.json` (e.g as `npm run restart-me`).

How can we restart a NODE JS server without using `Nodemon` ?

Comment: In case you run this on a linux-machine `systemctl restart [your-service-name]` would be sufficient.. If you want to restart it on crash, then put `Restart=always` in your .service-file. If you want to restart it on a specific date and time or interval, a cron job could do the trick..

Comment: First you need to come up with a way for the JS program to accept input from outside (e.g. via a signal or an HTTP request) which tells it to quit. Then you need to have it quit when it is told to do so. Then you need to write a program to send that input to it. Which bit are you having trouble with?  Alternatively you need to write the program in something that does most of that for you (like Nodemon)

Comment: @iLuvLogix — `systemctl restart [your-service-name]` is only sufficient if it was written as a service in the first place. There's no suggestion that it has been.

Comment: @Quentin Agreed - but that's mostly the case in a PROD-env..

Comment: @Quentin Another option would be a GET-request (as you suggested) - maybe via postman, which triggers a `shell.execute(...)` which restarts the app if nodemon isn't an option. Let's see if 
OP can clarify..

Comment: @iLuvLogix — How could shell.execute restart the app? I can see it spawning a second copy easily enough.

Comment: @Quentin by invoking a script that stops & starts or restarts the app (`ps, grep & kill`) ? Sry btw - it's `shell.exec(..)`..

Comment: That strikes me as a very unsafe approach to finding the right app to kill.

Comment: @Quentin Also agreed, but I didn't say that this approach is best-practise or flawless/safe - it was just a suggestion ;) `ps -aef | grep node` returns the full path to the node and executed scripts, so I guess you could find the right one to kill.. But again - I'm aware that this is a bit of a dirty hack..